# creating bar graph in php

Tags: php, bar-chart

How can I create graphs like this..
[image]

```
<?= format_size($this->space_used); ?> out of <?= format_size($this->total_space); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a couple divs with background colors and borders.

Comment: +1. Using PHP for generating stuff like this is total overkill. 

Here are lots and lots of examples that can be used with no javascript required: http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/04/16-usable-css-graph-and-bar-chart-tutorials-and-techniques/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that is not a bar graph, it is a progress bar.

As far as implementing this goes, my preference would be to use JavaScript to do the actual rendering. For example, have a look at the [jQuery UI Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/).

Otherwise, since this appears to be static data, you could calculate the percentage in the PHP script and then either generate an image on-the-fly or pick from a set of predefined images (EG: progress_10_pct, progress_20_pct, etc). Or as others have mentioned, just use some HTML/CSS markup to give the appearance of the bar - the choice is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Sample html :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.container 
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

}

.meter
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="meter">
&nbsp
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/3c015b3e6d6839827d2700aa1ed33ad4.png](http://grab.by/grabs/3c015b3e6d6839827d2700aa1ed33ad4.png)

Of course this only works if its static data, if its dynamic then you need some javascript, either by using a jQuery plugin as mentioned, or rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to use PHP, you could use the gd library - [look at this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php).

Otherwise I would recommend using just a couple of divs -

```
<div class="bar_container">
    <div class="bar" style="width: <?= $percentage ?>%;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery progress bar to do this easily http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

For a progress bar have a table with one row and two columns. Adjust width as percentage of area.

btw, we use [OpenFlashChart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/). it allows you to create bar/pie/line/scattered etc. and it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Completely off the top of my head, so caveat emptor...

```
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
#progressbar {
    display:inline-block;
    color:gray;
    width:50%;
}
#progressbar div {
    margin:0;
}
#progressbar > div {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}
#progressbar > div > div{
    background-color:green;
    width:<?php echo sprintf("%.0f", $u/$t); ?>%;
    height:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
...

Disk Space Usage <div id="progressbar"><?php echo "{$u} MB / {$t} MB"; ?><br><div></div></div>
```